# Run commands on host when Docker containers start and stop

Tags: docker

On a firewalled Docker host you must add rules to open and close ports when containers start or stop.

One way to do it is to create a Systemd unit file per container and open/close ports with ExecStartPre/ExecStopPost directives. This has the disadvantage that relies on an external service management system and cannot use restart policies from Docker itself.

Is there a way to solve this problem with only Docker provided facilities?

The most generic solution I can think of is a facility (a plugin maybe?) to execute execute arbitrary commands on specified container events. A hooks mechanism in other words. Does Docker has something like this?

Answer (score 0):

So how some firewall tools (like dfw, love it) do it is to actually, as you say, listen to events and act on them. I think, this is the way to go at the moment. Not sure if they will implement hooks later but listening to events is actually absolutely fine

Answer (score -1):

You can use ENTRYPOINT on docker to execute script during start up, and on this shell script you put a hook on SIGTERM using trap command

ie. create shell script start.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

stop() {
   echo "container is being stopped"
}

trap 'stop' #

... other command ...
```

Next you can hook `ENTRYPOINT` of docker to start.sh above

Comment: `ENTRYPOINT` script runs **inside** container. I want it to run **outside** container. Why? Because otherwise I need to give `NET_ADMIN` capability to the container to edit firewall rules, something against the principle of least privilege.